# ApproachTo Hit A Third Party Web Service That Returns A 302 / Redirect

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services, .net-3.5

What would be a way (or best practice) to hit a third party web service (https://www.thirdParty.com/API/authentication) with POST that includes a specific set of parameters.  The parameters will include typical authentication info like token, user, email, etc, and if the third party service authenticates me successfully it will return a 302 Found Response which should then redirect to an appropriate third party source web page.

A friend of mine suggests to use Ajax behind the scenes and redirect when there is a 302, but I'm not sure of the correct way to do this.

Comment: Will you need to do this from a single page or varied pages on your site? I ask because this affects whether I'd suggest using a page method or a web service.

Comment: Well my requirement in general is to open a new window and then do all this logic.  Regardless of page method or web service, the approach should be the same.  Short term, single page.

Comment: BTW, please don't put things like "ASP.NET / C# : " into your titles. The tags do a better job.

Comment: @John Saunders, the edit was good enough.  comment was unnecessary. But good looking out bro

Comment: In what way was the comment unnecessary? How else would you have known that I prefer you not do this in the future?

Comment: Honestly it isn't a big deal. But I already knew from looking at the edit. And what you prefer, in all honesty, I care nothing for.  As well, you should not care about my preference either.  That is all it is, a preference. Everyone has a preference. Like I said, thank you for the edit, and good looking out.

Answer (score 0):

If you POST to the third party service and it issues a 302, then the browser will automatically follow the redirect.

There's is no need for any AJAX, you can issue that POST directly from the HTML form, assuming to have suitable levels of encryption to protect this data (SSL).